# Can I buy games/DLCs with only a gift card and without a payment option on Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360

I am a little paranoid of putting my credit card on here cause I hear a lot of people can get their credit cards exposed, I want to buy a DLC for a game but I don't want to buy it with my credit card, is it possible that if I buy a gift card and put in the code, I can buy the DLC with the gift card? or do I sill have to put in my credit card info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get a gift card from the store and enter the (i believe its 25 digit) code you should be able to redeem the gift card.  It has been much safer since the xbox one came out to leave a card stored in the xbox but I am not sure how it is on the 360 at this point.  I believe if you go to the store and then click the button for entering a code you should be able to put that gift card code in right there.